# ScreenShot taken isn't of what's showing in the screen, but rather that of the header until a page size

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

When I try to take a screenshot, I added a scroll so that it can take a significant screenshot and not only the header. Right now, the picture is still taken from the header/top of the page.

Am I doing something wrong?

Screenshot method :

```
public void ScreenShot() {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("scroll(0,450);");
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm_ss");
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        String destDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + "test-output/ScreenShots";
        String FileName = "SoftAssertScreenshot_" + dtf.format(now) + ".png";
        String DestFile = destDir + "/" + FileName;
        File file = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        File ScreenshotName = new File(DestFile);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(file, ScreenshotName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Reporter.log("</br><font color='#73a9d0'>***************Screen Of the error****************</font>");
        Reporter.log("</br><img id='ErrorResult' src='" + DestFile + "' style='width:600px'/>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ashot it s the same principal as normal ScreenShot just it gives you a picture of the whole page
This is the same code but with Ashot:

```
public void ScreenShot() {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm_ss");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    String destDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + "test-output/ScreenShots";
    String FileName = "SoftAssertScreenshot_" + dtf.format(now) + ".png";
    String DestFile = destDir + "/" + FileName;
    Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(1000)).takeScreenshot(driver);
    BufferedImage image = screenshot.getImage(); 
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File(DestFile));
        System.out.println("test");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Reporter.log("</br><font color='#73a9d0'>***************Screen Of the error****************</font>");
    Reporter.log("</br><img id='ErrorResult' src='" + DestFile + "' style='width:600px'/>");
}
```